# Filter Library file from war file

Tags: java, maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I am using maven antrun plugin and i am trying to exclude library files from my war file. But i am not able to do it.  I know it can be done using maven war plugin but want it be excluded in maven antrun.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>1.8</version> 
  <executions> 
    <execution> 
      <phase>process-classes</phase> 
      <goals> 
        <goal>run</goal> 
      </goals> 
    </execution> 
  </executions> 
  <configuration> 
    <tasks> 
      <trying to exclude by giving *.jar>
    </tasks> 
  </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why do you want `maven-antrun-plugin`?

Comment: I am using maven antrun to copy my web.xm inside my war.

Comment: I can strongly recommend only using the war plugin (and then put the web.xml in the correct location in your source tree).  The benefit comes when you want IDE support during development as an IDE can parse the static configuration information in the pom and take all kinds of smart shortcuts, but for antrun anything can happen.

Comment: Yeah i agree, but i want to know whether it can be done using antrun plugin

Answer (score 1):

Use fileset to indicate the exclude jar of the libraries

```
<fileset dir="/lib">
    <exclude name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html